# Oracle - Group first column and rest to same line

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Table and desired output:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, Please click Table contents Tab for Question  :-)

Comment: What's the expected result if a an agent has several non-null values in a column?

Comment: Please type your question. You're unlikely to receive any answers based on a picture of your code. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584. And also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: My Table looks like this... Agent_id  132154 ,Region kkk (agent_id & region) are values in the same column (132154,kkk) are the corresponding values and so on. I've got it this way using a case statement. But i cant get it to one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no best way to achieve this, I don't think. However you could try;

```
SELECT agent_id, max(contact_no) as contact_no, max(address) as address,
       max(region) as region, max(owners_name) as owners_name, 
FROM <tablename>
GROUP BY agent_id
```

However, I would suggest that you seek to improve how data is placed into the database in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately editing the table structure is out of the question Simon, but your answer seem to work, Thanks...!